# Can I automatically turn off WIFI completely whenever not connected to a network on Android 10+

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, android-10

Here's my problem:
I used to run Lineage 16 on my Pixel3a, which still had the "profile" option where I could do things like "When my home network is not within reach, switch to another profile". I used this to turn off wifi when leaving the house and it worked very well. Important: This did not need my location services to be on to work.

Now I've upgraded to Lineage 17.1 (Android 10) and this option is gone. I am now looking into how to rebuild that functionality.
My phone is rooted (via Magisk), and as a software developer I am ready to use all tools I have available.

What I've tried: I've built an app that periodically checks if I am connected to one specific SSID (since that is all I can see on Android 10 anymore - "Am I connected to "my-ssid"?) and then turns of wifi using the shell and `su`like this:  `sudo("svc wifi disable")`. `sudo()` is my function that opens a process and talks to the shell.

The problem is I don't think there is a way I can guarantee my app always runs, and I'd like this to also work when the app is off? It doesn't even need to be a specific SSID, I'd be happy if my result is: "If we're not connected to a wifi network for more than 3min, turn wifi off.

so what other options do I have? `Tasker`, just like my own attempt, kind of works but only with location services on, *which I'd like to avoid*. What else can I do. Can I run some kind of script or a job just on the shell or so?
Is there anything I can do with *Magisk* or *Xposed*?

Happy for any help here - the internet is full of links and tips, but they all target older OS versions. Btw the source for my (extremely rough draft) app is [here](https://github.com/michpohl/auto-wifi-off) if anyone is curious.

Comment: if you have Xposed installed, you can try installing Xposed Edge. Open it, go to More triggers > Wifi Disconncted > Wifi > Turn off. It will turn off wifi as soon as the phone is disconnected from any network.

Answer (score 4):

With methods described below, when the phone disconnect from your wifi network, wifi will be immediately switched off. Also they don't require the Location Services to be on.

**A. Xposed Edge**

Open [Xposed Edge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jozein.xedge&hl=en_US&gl=US), go to More triggers > Wifi Disconncted > Wifi > Turn off.

**B. Macrodroid**

1. Open [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en_US&gl=US), click Add Macro.
2. Click the + on the right of Trigger. Click Connectivity > Wifi State Change > Disconnected from network. Click OK. Select your network(s).
3. Click the + on the right of Actions. Click Connectivity > Wifi Configure > Disable Wifi. Click Ok
4. Give your macro a name. Press back, save the macro. The macro will look like this:

[image: Switch Wifi off when disconnected from my network macro]

**C. Automate**

1. Open [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en_US&gl=US), click the + at the bottom of the screen to add a new flow.
2. Click +, Connectivity > Wifi enable?. Click the Wifi enable? block, set Options to Immediately. Click Save.
3. Click +, Connectivity > Wifi network connected?. Click Wifi network connected? block, Don't click on pick the network, but enter the network name (SSID) manually. Set Options to Immediately. Click Save.
4. Click +, Date & time > Delay. Click on the Delay block, set the duration to 3s. Click Save.
5. Click +, Connectivity > Wifi set state. Click on the Wifi set state block, select Off. Note that this block is not officially supported for Android 10+ and might not work.
6. Link the block has shown on the image below. Press back. Give your flow a name. Press Start to start the flow.

[image: IMG:]

**D. Ping your home router**
You can use a script in combination with the app mentioned to ping your home router. When the pings are successful, the phone wifi stays on. When they are unsuccessful, disable you phone wifi.